# iOS Take screenshot with GPUImageview Programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am working on GPUImageView Based application. I have implemented all functionality correctly but i am not able to capture Screenshot with GPUImageview.

[image]

Here I have also Attached Demo on My Github.

[GPUImageview Demo](https://github.com/badalpub1991/photo-Demo)

Note: I have tried to take a screenshot with **renderInContext:** but it not helpful for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i can see in your question,you have used GPUImageview. and GPUImageview used openGL so, you can achive your goal with using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

you can  use this method to achive your goal.

```
- (UIImage ​*)snapshot:(UIView *​)view
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
   [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return image;
}
```

for more information click on below link.

[On iOS 7 and later, how do I take a snapshot of my view and save the result in a UIImage?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html)

Comment: wow. you rock bro. Thanks for the replay. It works.

Comment: Happy to help you.